# Problem with saving data using Core Data in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, database, core-data

I'm trying to `save data to the core data` and then display it on another view controller. I have a `table view with custom cell, which have a button`. I've created a `selector`, so when we tap on the button in each of the cell, it should save all the data from the cell. Here is my `parent view controller`:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pecodeTableView: UITableView!
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    var savedNews = [SavedNews]()
    
    var newsTitle: String?
    var newsAuthor: String?
    var urlString: String?
    var newsDate: String?
    var isSaved: Bool = false
    
    private var articles = [Article]()
    private var viewModels = [NewsTableViewCellViewModel]()
    
    private let searchVC = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        pecodeTableView.delegate = self
        pecodeTableView.dataSource = self
        
        pecodeTableView.register(UINib(nibName: S.CustomCell.customNewsCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: S.CustomCell.customCellIdentifier)
        
        fetchAllNews()
        createSearchBar()
        loadNews()
        saveNews()
        countNewsToCategory()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func goToFavouritesNews(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: S.Segues.goToFav, sender: self)
    }
    
    private func fetchAllNews() {
        APICaller.shared.getAllStories { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let articles):
                self?.articles = articles
            self?.viewModels = articles.compactMap({
                NewsTableViewCellViewModel(author: $0.author ?? "Unknown", title: $0.title, subtitle: $0.description ?? "No description", imageURL: URL(string: $0.urlToImage ?? "")
                )
            })
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.pecodeTableView.reloadData()
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func createSearchBar() {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchVC
        searchVC.searchBar.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModels.count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: S.CustomCell.customCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomNewsCell
        cell.configure(with: viewModels[indexPath.row])
        cell.saveNewsBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.saveNewsBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapCellButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
    
    @objc func didTapCellButton(sender: UIButton) {
        guard viewModels.indices.contains(sender.tag) else { return }
        print("Done")// check element exist in tableview datasource
        if !isSaved {
            saveNews()
            print("success")
        }

        //Configure selected button or update model
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let article = articles[indexPath.row]
        
        
        
        guard let url = URL(string: article.url ?? "") else {
            return
        }
        
        let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    //Search
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        guard let text = searchBar.text, !text.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        APICaller.shared.Search(with: text) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let articles):
                self?.articles = articles
            self?.viewModels = articles.compactMap({
                NewsTableViewCellViewModel(author: $0.author ?? "Unknown", title: $0.title, subtitle: $0.description ?? "No description", imageURL: URL(string: $0.urlToImage ?? "")
                )
            })
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.pecodeTableView.reloadData()
                    self?.searchVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController {
    func loadNews() {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<SavedNews> = SavedNews.fetchRequest()
        
        do {
            let savedNews = try context.fetch(request)
            
            //Handle saved news
            if savedNews.count > 0 {
                isSaved = true
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func saveNews() {
        //Initialize the context
        let news = SavedNews(context: self.context)
        
        //Putting data
        news.title = newsTitle
        news.author = newsAuthor
        news.publishedAt = newsDate
        news.url = urlString
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error when saving data \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func countNewsToCategory() {
        //Initialize the context
        let request: NSFetchRequest<SavedNews> = SavedNews.fetchRequest()
        let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [
        ])
        request.predicate = predicate
        do {
            savedNews = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching data from category \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know where is the problem, I've created a `correct data model`, but data could not be saved. Here is my `model`:

```
import Foundation

struct APIResponse: Codable {
    let articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Codable {
    let author: String?
    let source: Source
    let title: String
    let description: String?
    let url: String?
    let urlToImage: String?
    let publishedAt: String
}

struct Source: Codable {
    let name: String
}
```

And also my `model in Core Data`: [image]

My `second view controller`, to which I want display the data:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FavouriteNewsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var favTableView: UITableView!
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    var savedNews = [SavedNews]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        favTableView.delegate = self
        favTableView.delegate = self
        
        loadSavedNews()
        
        favTableView.register(UINib(nibName: S.FavouriteCell.favouriteCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: S.FavouriteCell.favouriteCellIdentifier)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}

extension FavouriteNewsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return savedNews.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = favTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: S.FavouriteCell.favouriteCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! FavouritesCell
        
        print(savedNews)
        let article = savedNews[indexPath.row]
        if let articleTitle = article.title {
            cell.favTitle.text = articleTitle
        }
        if let articleAuthor = article.author {
            cell.favAuthor.text = articleAuthor
        }
        
        if let articleDesc = article.desc {
            cell.favDesc.text = article.desc
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
}

extension FavouriteNewsViewController {
    func loadSavedNews() {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<SavedNews> = SavedNews.fetchRequest()
        
        do {
            savedNews = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func deleteNews(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Delete From NSObject
        context.delete(savedNews[indexPath.row])
        
        // Delete From current News list
        savedNews.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        
        // Save deletion
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error when saving data \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The real problem is, you got bitten by the lack of design and architecture. A view controller is not a cake batter where you mix all the ingredients which constitute your whole app. So, first step is to refactor into components, apply Clean Code principles to the VC so that it becomes comprehensible, thereby also fixing data races and other setup issues.

Answer (score 0):

you did not assign your properties that you are trying to save

```
 newsTitle,newsAuthor,newsDate,urlString
```

seems these properties have nil value . make sure these properties have valid value before save .

Comment: Don't understand, I've made this in SaveNews()

Comment: yes but value of these properties are nil . assign  them  newsTitle = "value"

Comment: You are taking the values from the view controller, but where are you setting them?

Comment: Not really understand

Comment: func saveNews() {
        //Initialize the context
        let news = SavedNews(context: self.context)
        newsTitle = "newTilteValue"
        newsAuthor = "authorValue"
        newsDate = "dateValue"
        urlString = "urlString"
        //Putting data
        news.title = newsTitle
        news.author = newsAuthor
        news.publishedAt = newsDate
        news.url = urlString
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error when saving data \(error)")
        }
    }

Comment: replace with your savenews method

Comment: But I'm parsing the data from the internet, what I should put in this "". I think it's wrong

Comment: just after parsing assign newsTitle,newsAuthor,newsDate,urlString and then  save .

Comment: @dextermikles put a breakpoint on your `saveNews()` and step into it to see what values are being set, you should see the problem then.